# Should we say Al naharos bavel during Nissan?

Tags: bentching, nissan

There is a popular idea to not say Al Naharos Bavel before Birtkat HaMazon on days when tachnun is not said (see [here](https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/900458/rabbi-aryeh-lebowitz/saying-shir-hamaalos-and-al-naharos-bavel-before-bentching/)). Does that apply to all of Nissan?

Comment: Why wouldn't it?